# Scala - REPL - Issue with quoted named variable

Tags: scala

Why is that a problem in the REPL?

```
scala> var `var` = 10;
var: Int = 10

scala> `var` = `var` + 90;
<console>:14: error: empty quoted identifier
val $ires2 = ``var``
             ^
<console>:14: error: empty quoted identifier
val $ires2 = ``var``
                  ^
```

I think I have a variable with a valid (though weird) name.
I then run into an issue when I try to add some literal value to its current value.

Comment: Looks like a REPL bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tickets related to backquotes, such as [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8456).

More generally, [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9016).

With `-Dscala.repl.debug`,

```
object $read {
  ;

object $iw {
import $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.`var`
object $iw {

       `var` = `var` + 90

val $ires0 = ``var``
}
}

}
```